# How to process this string via regular expression

Tags: regex, string

my string style like this

```
expression1/field1+expression2*expression3+expression4/field2*expression5*expression6/field3
```

a real style mybe like this:

```
computer/(100)+web*mail+explorer/(200)*bbs*solution/(300)
```

"+" and "*"  represent operator
"computer","web"...represent expression
(100),(200) represent field num . field num may not exist.

I want process the string to this:

```
<computer>/(100)+web*<mail>+explorer/(200)*bbs*<solution>/(300)
```

rules like this

if expression length is more than 3 and its field is not (200), then add brackets to it.

Comment: Give more examples. Some useful ones too.

Comment: @iiduce, assuming your avatar is not the way you look like now, please try to write like a grown up. :)

Comment: Why isn't `explorer` bracketed? And why is `solution`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to mix regex with other language features. The complication arises from the fact that `field` appears before `expression`s, and lookbehind is usually more limited than lookforward.

In pseudo-Java-code, I recommend doing something like this:

```
String[] parts = input.split("/");

for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  if (!parts[i].startsWith("(200)"))
    parts[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("(?=[a-z]{4})([a-z]+)", "<$1>");
}

String output = parts.join("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use *just* regular expression.

You say "if expression length is more than 3 and its field is not (200), then add brackets to it"

I think a normal conditional statement is the best and clearest solutoion for this.

I think regular expressions are sometimes overused. Regexes are hard to read, and when a couple of conditional statements can do the same but more clearly, then I'd say the code quality is higher.

Comment: I disagree that regex is overused/hard to read. The reason why it isn't suitable here is because `field` appears before the `expression` to be bracketed, and lookbehind is usually more limited than lookforward. If `field` appears at the end of `expression`s, this is actually quite trivial and the regex is very readable.